# How to Specify other font to special characters

Tags: css

I am using NeuturaRegular and Avenir65Medium fonts for my website but when i give `'` symbol or any other special characters then that will display as `?` with green background so i dont want it to happen, some one told me that we can specify other font for special so any one please help me ....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

open [**fontsquirrel.com**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

upload your font, and choose Expert from radio buttons, there is an option `subsetting`, use `customs subsetting` and choose `characters` from check boxes as required.

And download the @fontface kit.

Comment: are you copying single quote `'` symbol from a word file?